# Load multiple files with Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have several files in my working directory:

- one.xml
- two.xml
- ...
- thousand.xml

I want to process it using Apache Camel File2 component. Something like:

```xml
<route>
    <from uri="file://inbox?idempotent=true&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=360" />
    <to uri="bean:processInbox"/>
</route>
```

Is it possible to read and process multiple files in one folder at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation http://camel.apache.org/file2.html:

> maxMessagesPerPoll: "An integer to define a maximum messages to gather
>   per poll..."

maxMessagesPerPoll=360 means that if you have - for example - 400 files in your directory, the first poll takes 360 and the remaining 40 will be taken in the next poll. 
However your bean:processInbox endpoint will only get 1 file as input(360 times for the first poll, 40 times for the second poll)

Comment: Sorry, may be my question is not correct. 

I understand the meaning of "maxMessagesPerPoll" option. I need process this thousand files by some portions (360 it is only example) more than one file.

And the main question is: how to give "bean:processInbox" more then one file? 360, 1000, 5 it isnot so important.

Comment: Then you have to aggregate the incoming files: http://camel.apache.org/aggregate-example.html

Comment: Maybe this will also help: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregator/AggregateGroupedExchangeTest.java

Comment: And this is maybe the perfect match for you http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html: 
completionFromBatchConsumer
false
This option is if the exchanges are coming from a Batch Consumer. Then when enabled the Aggregator2 will use the batch size determined by the Batch Consumer in the message header CamelBatchSize. See more details at Batch Consumer. This can be used to aggregate all files consumed from a File endpoint in that given poll.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your advices were really helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by giving your processor more than one file? Do you mean pass multiple file to the processor, for which the aggregator would work? Or, do you want multiple processors to be spinning, each working on a separate file in parallel?

Comment: Darius, the first variant. Many files goes to the one processor. I want to have List of files there.